# Provision of Web Analytics via visual studio - sharepoint 2010

Tags: 2010, search, auditing

Does anyone know how to provision web analytics via visual studio 2010 ?

I have got web analytics working for search results - ie: it will show me how many searches have been performed, top search phrases etc. Its great that its working, but now i need to ensure i can get it working via visual studio.

Any one have any ideas where i start?

Many thanks

Bill

Comment: Web Analytics is a Service Application. Sure, it's possibly to programmatically create a Service Application instance from a Farm-scoped Feature Receiver, is this what you want to do?

Comment: You should also consider if programmatically configuring this functionality is best or if you can create a powershell script for this one off task?

Answer (score 2):

You should use PowerShell for provisioning your service apps. For once, you do not always know where your SA's will end up depending on farm topology (dedicated application server etc), so automated farm configuration should be done in PowerShell.

An example (taken from [Todd Carter's blog](http://todd-carter.com/post/2010/04/26/The-Wizard-Likes-His-GUIDs.aspx), but there are several examples out there)

```
Write-Host "Creating Web Analytics Service and Proxy..."
$stagerSubscription = "<StagingDatabases><StagingDatabase ServerName='$databaseServerName' DatabaseName='StagerDB'/></StagingDatabases>"
$reportingSubscription = "<ReportingDatabases><ReportingDatabase ServerName='$databaseServerName' DatabaseName='WarehouseDB'/></ReportingDatabases>"
New-SPWebAnalyticsServiceApplication -Name $WebAnalyticsSAName -ApplicationPool $saAppPoolName -ReportingDataRetention 20 -SamplingRate 100 -ListOfReportingDatabases $reportingSubscription -ListOfStagingDatabases $stagerSubscription > $null 
New-SPWebAnalyticsServiceApplicationProxy -Name "$WebAnalyticsSAName Proxy" -ServiceApplication $WebAnalyticsSAName > $null
Get-SPServiceInstance | where-object {$_.TypeName -eq "Web Analytics Web Service"} | Start-SPServiceInstance > $null
Get-SPServiceInstance | where-object {$_.TypeName -eq "Web Analytics Data Processing Service"} | Start-SPServiceInstance > $null
```